# JSoup BodyAsBytes connection to FileOutputStream to save temp file doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, cookies, download, jsoup

I used JSoup to parse a website with cookies. I want to download a file from the website using JSoup and the cookies which were saved in a hashmap using this piece of code:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://www.webpage.com/downloadpage).execute();
Map<String, String> cookies = res.cookies();
```

So when I try to download the file, I use this:

```
downloadFile(Jsoup.connect("http://www.webpage.com/file.ext).cookies(cookies).ignoreContentType(true).execute().bodyAsBytes());
```

and

```
private void downloadFile(byte[] fileByteArray) {
    try {
        File temprFile = File.createTempFile("tempfile", "ext", getCacheDir());
        temprFile.deleteOnExit();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(temprFile);
        fos.write(fileByteArray);
        fos.close();

        }  catch (MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        String s = ex.toString();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The program runs without errors, but when I try to open the temporary file, it appears the file isn't complete. Each time, exactly 1.408.576 bytes are downloaded. For example when I download an mp3-file this way, the temporary file contains only 40 seconds of the original file. What am I missing here?

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the basics? Does the temp file wind up being the same size as the HTTP response? Is the original file on the remote server actually complete, or could it really just be the first 40 seconds of the track?

Comment: I'm not sure, if this could be the case, but you're saving to the `cacheDir` of `Android`. According to the documentation there could be a limitation as to how much you can save there. See here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies. The file on the server is definitely complete, no problem streaming in Chrome on Win7. I've also tried saving the file to the external sd-card, but it ends up the same way. From each file on the server exactly 1.048.576 bytes are downloaded and written into a file in the cache memory or the sd card.

Comment: @BramDeBacker is it from the same place, you're trying to download or have you tried different websites to download from?

Comment: can you log the length of fileByteArray in the beginning of the "downloadFile" method? this way you will know if you are recieving incomplete data or if the system is limiting your writing into the temporary file.

Comment: I just tried to download a file from a website, using `Jsoup`, as you describe in your question. I get the same length - the problem is the `byte[]` - it can hold more than 1.048.576 bytes...
Besides, it doesn't look like `Jsoup` is designed to download files ;-)

Comment: @Darwin it can or it can't?

Comment: @Darwin the array limit in java is close to max integer and that is more than the number in the examples above. but thanks to your effort, it was  obvious that jsoup is limiting the array. searching on SO lead to the following post where the accepted answers shows that JSoup limits the download by default to 1MB. but it can be changed as seen there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511614/how-to-limit-download-size-with-jsoup

Comment: Interesting - and the explanation makes sense; to avoid memory leaks ;-) But as it seems like Jsoup can only return a byte[] and not a stream (or maybe it can) it wouldn't be suitable for bigger downloads anyways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guess I came to soon here to ask my question. Found the solution myself in the GitHub docs for JSoup. Thanks anyway for the responses!
https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jsoup/Connection.java

```
/**
 * Set the maximum bytes to read from the (uncompressed) connection into the body, before the connection is closed,
 * and the input truncated. The default maximum is 1MB. A max size of zero is treated as an infinite amount (bounded
 * only by your patience and the memory available on your machine).
 * @param bytes number of bytes to read from the input before truncating
 * @return this Connection, for chaining
 */
public Connection maxBodySize(int bytes);
```

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I added 0 to `maxBodySize(0)` and got full video downloaded. example `Jsoup.connect(url).maxBodySize(0).ignoreContentType(true).execute().bodyAsBytes()`